# Вывод циклом 4ех элементов массива

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Сразу код:

```
$works = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM port_works");
    while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($works)) {
        if($b > 4) break; // Попытка :)
        echo $b['test'];
}
```

Cуть такая. Получаем из БД ряды информации и выводим ее на экран циклом. Но нужно вывести только 4 первых ряда, а дальше прекратить цикл. Я попытался дописать `if($b > 4) break;`, но ничем не помогло, а только испортило) Как сделать такую ерундовину?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ограничьте число результатов сразу в MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM port_work LIMIT 4
```

Тогда точно будет не более 4-х результатов. Ещё подумайте о сортировке - какие показывать в начале.

```
$works = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM port_works LIMIT 4");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($works)) {
    echo $b['test'];
}
```

Comment: Да, вчера после того как задал вопрос вспомнил и сделал так) А с сортировкой ведь просто ORDER BY. Не?

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос...

Может лучше завести какую-нибудь переменную "счетчик"?

```
$i = 0;
$works = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM port_works");
    while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($works)) {
        if($i > 4) break; 
        echo $b['test'];
        $i++;

}
```